# Rails Devise+Omniauth Facebook redirect to users/sign_up fails

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

So, im using Rails 4, ominiauth and facebook ominiauth but when i try login always redirect to  users/sign_up in devise to create a new user, in my console appear this:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCGbVuW0AV8d4pfkPWHjSWiM6pLY03rmQwHECQfhZiH2E5wJT8OpeV64SYvCAjsf3nVJrpgeUVFn5CDjUuYoOjbY078fQPwIktgsUh5E7TFYpS3_KLLfhuEEd1ilzT4LHw5SPV78bpHe3-5wLEip2pAkQ0u4M3AUBooNvJyAGLaQqBzyG3NHYTa3DembMOXAgqeZbZubrWLBk6NPoVmUg6-mPp1glmPoUbyZ2S1fE2ynOhbwCqMk-n8sqCmlN9j8SSG6plxZzCUcoWMOEchkYUMBi6TW2UOEamVRSQZcOecxAq8fn0VG7Z_gwDk1VcOTV8&state=58dc14ece55d93513bd89dc06590f0f6cb2d8568c2aac35a" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-08 23:02:50 -0300
I, [2013-08-08T23:02:50.902450 #3121]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQCGbVuW0AV8d4pfkPWHjSWiM6pLY03rmQwHECQfhZiH2E5wJT8OpeV64SYvCAjsf3nVJrpgeUVFn5CDjUuYoOjbY078fQPwIktgsUh5E7TFYpS3_KLLfhuEEd1ilzT4LHw5SPV78bpHe3-5wLEip2pAkQ0u4M3AUBooNvJyAGLaQqBzyG3NHYTa3DembMOXAgqeZbZubrWLBk6NPoVmUg6-mPp1glmPoUbyZ2S1fE2ynOhbwCqMk-n8sqCmlN9j8SSG6plxZzCUcoWMOEchkYUMBi6TW2UOEamVRSQZcOecxAq8fn0VG7Z_gwDk1VcOTV8", "state"=>"58dc14ece55d93513bd89dc06590f0f6cb2d8568c2aac35a"}
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 81 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'facebook' AND `users`.`uid` = '100003808270452' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'mail@mail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_up
```

I know failed but i dont know because what, he search and finds the user but because what dont return sucess ?

the action is:

```
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

If someone can help me is very important to me, thanks much much much.

Comment: Having a similar problem setting this up on Rails 4 using http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2013/03/rails-3-devise-omniauth-and-google/

Answer (score 0):

You have ot specify two URL while calling Auth.
1) Success which will redirect sucesses params after successfule login
2) Error if anything bad happens.

These you have to specify while you create the FB application with your domain name.

```
callback_url / callback_path
```

is the name of the variable is above that you can pass via the call.

Ref https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Hope this helps.